# Elasticsearch bulk manual index refreshing

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch, bulkinsert, elasticsearch-net

Currently my index has this option:

```
{
  "index" : {
    "refresh_interval" : "-1"
  }
}
```

Which should mean that index needs to be manually refreshed once data has been pushed into it to make content searchable.

My application, which indexes data, refreshes index once bulk inserting is done.

Is this a good approach or is there a other recommended way to do that?

Comment: Why isn't your app setting back the `refresh_interval` ?

Comment: Is there any need to do that? I'd like my content to be refreshed only if something has been modified there. Would it be better to disable `refresh_interval` before indexing and enable it after indexing is done?

Comment: Yes, I thought I suggested the same in my previous comment...

Comment: Out of curiousity. Is there any benefit by it this way? Looks like you're someone who could answer it.

Comment: You avoid continuous segments merging, which eats up some CPU and a lot of IO.